# What kind of "direct product" is the $p$-adic solenoid?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I'm confused about this paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number:

> $p$-adic integers can be extended to $p$-adic solenoids $\mathbb{T}_{p}$ in the same way that integers can be extended to the real numbers, as the direct product of the circle ring $\mathbb{T}$ and the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

I don't think the real numbers are the kind of topological product (or the kind of group product) that I'm used to of the integers and the circle, and neither is the $p$-adic solenoid the usual kind of product of the $p$-adic integers and the circle. Is there a more specific name for this kind of product, and what is it?

Only looking at the topological structure, the only relationship I can see is this one:

- There's a map $\pi_{\mathbb R} : \mathbb R \to \mathbb T$ such that for each point $x \in \mathbb T$, $\pi_{\mathbb R}^{-1}(x)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and furthermore there is some open neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $\pi_{\mathbb R}^{-1}(O)$ is homeomorphic to $O \times \mathbb Z$.
- There's a map $\pi_{\mathbb T_p} : \mathbb T_p \to \mathbb T$ such that for each point $x \in \mathbb T$, $\pi_{\mathbb T_p}^{-1}(x)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$ and furthermore there is some open neighborhood $O$ of $x$ such that $\pi_{\mathbb T_p}^{-1}(O)$ is homeomorphic to $O \times \mathbb Z_p$.

But I don't know anything about what this kind of topological product is called, nor how to define this kind of product for topological groups or rings.

Comment: No, the p-adic solenoid is not a product, Wikipedia is wrong on this.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ is the universal cover $U(G)$ of $G=\Bbb{R/Z}$, this is the kind of "product" you are thinking to, composing a manifold $M$ with its fundamental group $\pi_1(M,x_0)$ to get the set of  homotopy classes of curves $x_0\to ?$ in $M$. For $\Bbb{T}_p=\varprojlim \Bbb{R/p^n Z}$ not sure of what it is, doesn't seem easy to visualize. We'll have $\Bbb{T}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p=\Bbb{R/Z}$, this is a bit similar to $U(\Bbb{R/Z})/\pi_1(\Bbb{R/Z})=\Bbb{R/Z}$.

Comment: @reuns: It's some unknown Wikipedia editor who does not understand inverse limits edited the article on 04/03/2020 and introduced an error.

Comment: Anyway the topological generalization should be to consider the inverse limit of all the (locally) finite coverings of a manifold, this is analogous to the etale topology stuffs.

Comment: The original poster mentions "the circle ring ". I am familiar with the circle as a *group*. But what is "the circle ring"???

Answer (score 4):

You are right and the linked Wikipedia article on p-adic numbers is wrong about this. The easiest way to see this is to note that each p-adic solenoid $T_p$ is connected, while the product of p-adic integers $Z_p$ with the circle is not connected.  The correct statement is that $T_p$ fibers over $S^1$ with fibers $Z_p$.

Answer (score 1):

This construction is the inverse limit of $\mathbf R/p^k\mathbf Z$ over all nonnegative integers $k$.  Since the appendix to chapter 1 of A. Robert's "A Course in p-adic Analysis" for details.